# Create Multiple Files in C program using command line arguments

Tags: c, file, command-line-arguments

I am trying to create a C program which has a text.txt file with 50 lines. This text.txt file should be split into 5 files such as text_part1.txt, text_part2.txt and so on. The 50 lines in the text.txt file should be copied equally to 10 lines each in 5 files.

All these has to be done by using command line arguments. I am a beginner in C and have just started to code. I don't know how to use command line arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
 FILE *ptr_readfile;
 FILE *ptr_writefile;
 char line [100]; 
 char fileoutputname[10];
 int filecounter=1, linecounter=1;

 ptr_readfile = fopen("C:/home/dir/sample_pg/data/text.txt","r");
 if (!ptr_readfile)
 return 1;

 sprintf(fileoutputname, "file_part%d", filecounter);
 ptr_writefile = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");

 while (fgets(line, sizeof line, ptr_readfile)!=NULL) 
 {
    if (linecounter == 5)
        {
        fclose(ptr_writefile);
        linecounter = 1;
        filecounter++;
        sprintf(fileoutputname, "file_part%d", filecounter);
        ptr_writefile = fopen(fileoutputname, "w");
        if (!ptr_writefile)
            return 1;
        }
    fprintf(ptr_writefile,"%s\n", line);
    linecounter++;
 }
 fclose(ptr_readfile);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm) is the first one to come up in a google search.

Comment: okay...Thnaks for your time, in replying immediately. Please tell me whether the code is correct to create multiple files because i dont find any text file in the specified path

Comment: You need to **compile with all warnings & debug info** (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) then learn how to **use the debugger**

Comment: Your program has bugs. It is your duty to find them.

Comment: If my answer fits, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

To get the program's arguments, you need to define your `main`  function with an argument count (conventionally named `argc`) and and argument array (conventionally named `argv`), so something  as

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
  for (int ix=1; ix<argc; ix++) {
     FILE* fil = fopen(argv[ix], "r");
     if (!fil) { perror(argv[ix]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

When you compile this (with some other needed code) into an executable `foo.exe`  and run `foo.exe a b c` on the terminal, `argc` is 4 and you have

```
      argc == 4 &&
      strcmp(argv[0], "foo.exe") == 0 &&
      strcmp(argv[1], "a") == 0 &&
      strcmp(argv[2], "b") == 0 &&
      strcmp(argv[3], "c") == 0 &&
      argv[4] == NULL
```

Notice that it is a good habit to call `perror` on failure of a function like `fopen`

BTW, you forgot to call `fclose` in your program. You might learn more about `fflush` also. And you should prefer `snprintf` to `sprintf`  to avoid [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Learn more about, and be very scared of, [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Please take the habit of compiling with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) then learn how to use the debugger.

Read [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [fclose(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html), [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html), [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) and take the habit to read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every function that you want to use.

See also [csplit](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/csplit-invocation.html); you might take some inspiration by studying the source code of the [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) package [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) implementing it on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts of all the people who answered me, I have completed my program...